# Cannot convert <QueryDict: {u..to decimal after limiting foreign key

Tags: django, foreign-keys

I have a django modelForm that it was being submitted successfully until I added this code in my forms.py:

```
def __init__(self, own_id=None, **kwargs):
    super(WebrequestsForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    if own_id:

       self.fields['veh_id1'].queryset = Vehicles.objects.filter(own_id1=own_id)
       self.fields['veh_id2'].queryset = Vehicles.objects.filter(own_id2=own_id)
```

I did this because I want to limit the entries of the above foreign keys. After that only the related choices appeared in the form as expected but the form couldn't be submitted.

I get the following error:

`Cannot convert <QueryDict: {u'attachment2flag': [u'on'], u'nod_id1': [u'70'], u'vrd_id': [u'1'], u'nod_id2': [u'50'], u'tel': [u'2310566167'], u'directiondb': [u'1'], u'rdateto': [u'1/2/2013'], u'sendmethod': [u'1'], u'fax': [u'2310511559'], u'submitdate': [u'1'], u'email': [u'info@rdfvfvd.com'], u'veh_id2': [u'878'], u'veh_id1': [u'2978'], u'returnflag': [u'1'], u'reqtype': [u'1'], u'remarks': [u'1'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'1Vhl04H1HgelkDdnS6IsCw61dtSyitkX'], u'rdatefrom': [u'1/2/2012'], u'id': [u'22065'], u'own_id': [u'148']}> to Decimal`

veh_id1 and veh_id2 are decimal fields so I guess that with the filtering something wrong tries to be saved there. How can I return in the dropdown list the id of the object with this `self.fields['veh_id1'].queryset = Vehicles.objects.filter(own_id1=own_id)` that needs to be saved?

I can sense where the problem is but I have no idea how to solve this cause I'm newbie in django.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. The prob was in the call of my modelForm's initialization.
Instead of the 'expected': `form = MyForm(request.POST,  own_instance.id)`
tried `form = MyForm(data=request.POST, own_id=own_instance.id)`, and it worked
because there is a distinction between positional and keyword arguments as I finally discovered.